# CNN - Train a network of images considering the image group classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a CNN that will classify images.
I know that each group of images (can be 2 - 10 images in group) is classified to the same label.

So if I predict that 8 images from this group are from class A and 2 from class B, I want to make the network predict that all 10 images are from class A.

Till now, I created a network that will classify each image without referring to the fact that they are divided into groups.

The output suppose to be the prediction for **each image** and not to group of images.
I thought about adding option in the network that will get the major label in each group and classify all the images in this group to the same label.
Can I make it without creating a new network?
And if so, how can I make it?

I used the following network:
(input is all images in shape (pixels, pixels,1))

```
def model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='linear',input_shape=(pixels,pixels,1),padding='same'))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(128, activation='linear'))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
  model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
  return model
```

Thank you!

Edit -
I tried to use callback in order to do the change during the training.

```
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, train_df, val_df, save_file, model, features):
        self.train_df = train_df
        self.val_df = val_df
        self.model = model
        self.features = features

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
```

Comment: You have an indenation error.

Comment: Why not a function that consumes the predictions and make a consensus? Ping me here and I can help you if you need. I think that you are overcomplicating things here.

Comment: the problem is that I need to use it during the training of the network. since I know that each group of images is from the same class and I want the training to use that fact. Maybe I wrong and there is another way because I'm new to CNN and I would like to hear any idea @aerijman

Comment: use a callback. I am quite rusted but if you need help with that after you tried a little bit, let me know and I will try myself.

Comment: As you mentioned, I tried to create a custom callback but I couldn't find a way to train my network and change the predictions.  I tried to use on_epoch_end but couldn't find a way to do it. I would be happy to any help. Edited the question with callback function. @aerijman

Answer (score 0):

Example code that training a `mnist` classifier and with group prediction:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers
import numpy as np

BATCH_SIZE = 32
LATENT_DEM = 128

def _normalize_img(img, label):
    img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.
    return (img, label)

train_dataset, test_dataset = tfds.load(name="mnist", split=['train', 'test'], as_supervised=True)

# Build your input pipelines
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(_normalize_img)

test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(_normalize_img)

def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='linear',input_shape=(28, 28, 1),padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='linear'))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    return model

model = build_model()

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the network
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=3)

# Take group_num of images with the same class_index, e.g take 10 images of handwriting number 0
same_class_imgs = []
class_index = 0
group_num = 10
for data in train_dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
    for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        if data[1][i] == class_index:
            same_class_imgs.append(data[0][i])
    if len(same_class_imgs) >= group_num:
        same_class_imgs = same_class_imgs[:10]
        break

predictions = model.predict(np.array(same_class_imgs))
class_predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
# Get every class with maximum count in a predictions, 
# If model predict something like Class 0: 4, Class 2: 4, Class 6: 2 for all 10 images then result will be [0, 2]
u, c = np.unique(class_predictions, return_counts = True)
group_predictions = u[c == c.max()]
print("Model outputs:\n{}\nClass predictions for each:\n{}\nGroup predictions:\n{}\n".format(predictions, class_predictions, group_predictions))
```

Outputs:

```
Epoch 1/3
1875/1875 [==============================] - 25s 13ms/step - loss: 0.1151 - accuracy: 0.9636
Epoch 2/3
1875/1875 [==============================] - 26s 14ms/step - loss: 0.0373 - accuracy: 0.9887
Epoch 3/3
1875/1875 [==============================] - 27s 15ms/step - loss: 0.0276 - accuracy: 0.9918
Model outputs:
[[9.99998093e-01 4.44641879e-09 3.59849594e-07 1.63150361e-11
  5.72367154e-10 1.30235627e-08 2.22519478e-08 2.74096346e-09
  1.35854119e-08 1.50564949e-06]
 [9.99993443e-01 4.39691888e-07 3.04043715e-06 6.97965232e-13
  2.71462852e-10 1.95115590e-11 2.83727672e-06 1.77562035e-10
  8.74899158e-08 4.50125714e-09]
 [9.99771059e-01 7.68102666e-08 1.70877684e-04 5.31888533e-09
  1.18625154e-09 1.55892820e-07 5.27070406e-05 1.39944865e-08
  1.69486464e-06 3.51022732e-06]
 [9.97043431e-01 4.56344900e-08 4.86983163e-06 5.02740682e-10
  1.26683688e-07 2.26395724e-09 2.95107951e-03 3.57114269e-11
  3.71302264e-07 1.21673409e-07]
 [9.99990821e-01 3.98899509e-08 1.80275507e-07 9.63127977e-09
  6.10572037e-10 1.61982803e-06 8.47767296e-08 3.85314580e-09
  3.89608113e-06 3.24082566e-06]
 [9.99009490e-01 4.41650997e-07 3.74904607e-06 1.01597159e-07
  1.90468157e-07 5.84926011e-06 1.67861625e-04 6.61629773e-09
  1.19658958e-04 6.92503527e-04]
 [9.99953389e-01 7.85282879e-08 1.22815834e-06 3.36330047e-10
  9.96207630e-11 7.86476903e-06 3.04561325e-07 2.15532872e-08
  3.20932595e-05 5.02664489e-06]
 [9.99999881e-01 8.90605922e-10 1.58526674e-07 1.08922321e-14
  5.17258491e-13 4.65424088e-11 2.56549915e-09 1.93356355e-11
  1.11570158e-08 6.98878289e-09]
 [9.99998450e-01 4.95704171e-08 1.38500775e-06 7.40387501e-14
  5.10533109e-12 5.59060465e-10 6.39804432e-10 4.76541073e-09
  4.51906317e-08 9.17944476e-08]
 [9.99998093e-01 4.56725751e-08 7.49201376e-08 3.43272437e-12
  5.57741457e-11 2.99988500e-07 1.19160859e-08 2.33604425e-08
  1.12858947e-06 3.71466854e-07]]
Class predictions for each:
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
Group predictions:
[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! But I want the classification for each image, and just use the fact that every group of images are from the same class. Can I make it?  @Mr. For Example

Comment: @user2026 I believe I did exactly what you want, It is classification for each image as usual, and my code after training the model is showing you how you can do group prediction use the fact that every group of images are from the same class, `class_predictions` in my code is prediction for each image in the group

Comment: @user2026 If you want propagate the group prediction to the shape of `(number of images in group , )` then just using `np.repeat(group_predictions[0], group_num)`, but be aware that there maybe the case group predictions length is not `1`, i.e the model classify same amount of image for two class and they both maximum, in that case you many not want propagate the group prediction

Comment: Can I make it during the training? and not in the prediction. @Mr. For Example

Comment: @user2026 Why you want using group prediction in the training instead of training for each outputs? both have same computational complexity but group prediction will led to lot worse model, The model will stop improve when outputs have majority of correct prediction, and the gradient will be extreme when outputs don't have majority of correct prediction, but most importantly if you change the outputs of model then there will be no gradients flow back to training the model